# adb error type 3 Activity class {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.WallpaperCropActivity} does not exist

Tags: adb, 8.1-oreo, wallpaper

I tried to change my wallpaper via adb. As I'm new to Android and don't know much about its activities, launcher etc. I don't know where my mistake is. I have found following adb command:

```
adb shell am start -d file:///sdcard/Download/test1.jpg -a android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER -f 0x1 com.android.launcher3/.WallpaperCropActivity
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.WallpaperCropActivity} does not exist.
```

I tried another command which shows a message on the device screen:

```
Picture couldn't load as wallpaper
```

adb command which shows the message:

```
adb shell am start -a android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -d file:///sdcard/Download/$bild -t 'image/' -e mimeType 'image/'
```

The devices OS is Android 8.1.
Does anyone know how to change the wallpaper (Home- and Lockscreen) of an Android device with adb?

Comment: What device is it? Which launcher are you using? Is the Android rooted? And, can I know why you are resorting to adb for this?

Comment: @Firelord I think it‘s Launcher3. The Device is not rooted. I want to set some settings for those devices. I have to do these „default settings“ very often. A part of our default settings is a special background. So I thought i could create a Script which sets the picture that I want as background.